# Conditional summary

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want to implement such report: there are invoices, each invoice has sum and currency. In the report can be invoices with different currencies. What I need is to show in summary total sum for each currency.

For example, report has 2 EUR invoices and 3 USD invoices. So in the summary should be 2 records: total for USD and total for EUR. Is it posible to implement it with jasperreports or I have to create a list of totals at the java-side?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, you can do it for example with help of `iReport`

Comment: I can't find any examples of such thing in iReport documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible, but it's a bit complicated if you really want it in the Summary band. You'll need 2 groups: Currency and Invoice. Then create a variable where you add whatever summed info that you need for each invoice/currency. Display that variable in the Summary band.